# Facebook - how to go directly to the request permission dialog with an iframe app?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, permissions, authentication

When a user accesses my facebook app via http://apps.facebook.com/myappxxxxx, I want it to immediately show the request permissions fb dialog - like so many others do.

I have tried all sorts of things - including php redirect using the getLoginUrl, javascript window location redirect using the same.

The problem is that it shows a big facebook icon instead of the request permissions.  However, if you click on that icon, it in fact goes to the correct request permissions page!

Does anyone know how to redirect to the facebook permissions page properly?

I am using the PHP api and JavaScript SDK with an iFrame FB app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the exact same problem a while ago. Here's a little hack:

```
if(!$me) {  
    $url =   "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?"
                ."client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&"
                ."redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/APP_SLUG/&"
                ."scope=user_photos,publish_stream";
    echo "<script language=javascript>window.open('$url', '_parent', '')</script>";
} else {
    your code...
}
```

How it looks in my code (a bit dirty, I had a deadline):

```
require_once 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$appid = '';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $appid,
  'secret' => '',
  'cookie' => true,
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();

$me = null;
if ($session) {
  try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
}
if(!$me) {
    // here we redirect for authentication:
    // This is the code you should be looking at:
    $url =   "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?"
            ."client_id=$appid&"
            ."redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/APP_SLUG/&"
            ."scope=user_photos,publish_stream";
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
        <head>
            <title>Göngum til góðs</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
            <script language=javascript>window.open('<?php echo $url ?>', '_parent', '')</script>
        </head>

        <body>
            Loading...
        </body>
    </html>

    <?php
    exit;
} else {
    your code ...
}
```

A simple header redirect won't work since it will only redirect your iframe. Javascript is needed to access the _parent window.

### Edit

Keep in mind that there is a proper way to do this (see answer below) and I do not recommend doing this. But hey, what ever floats your boat...

Comment: Finally, YES, this worked.   I also used the PHP api to get the loginurl : $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); and set $url to that.

Comment: Question - is there a difference / advantage between using window.top.location.href vs. window.open (_parent) ?

Comment: FYI - I had to build the URL manually instead of using getLoginUrl as it was redirecting to my site instead of the fb apps url.

Comment: I guess window.top.location.href should work just the same. And yes, I also found out the hard way that `$facebook->getLoginUrl();` is useless.

Comment: I figured out later you can use getLoginUrl() as long as you specify the 'next' and other url's and put in your apps.facebook... url

Comment: Cool, can you post your new solution as another answer to your question, please? It might be of some use for me in the future. ;)

Comment: `getSession()` is the old method, you should be using `getUser()`

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you try the [Facebook authenticated referrals](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication/#referrals)? It's the proper solution for such problem. Since it asks Facebook to traps the non-connected users and redirect them directly to the connect page.

This insure that all of the users are connected to your app by default.

Comment: This is the real answer. The most voted one is an hack and as such may result in a temporary ban.

Comment: Facebook removed  Facebook authenticated referrals. Too bad!

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option:

```
<script>
    (function () {
        var url = 'your_permission_url';
        window.top.location.href = url;
    } ());
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The url should be from getLoginUrl($PARAMS). It worked for me.
In your case,

`$PARAMS = array('scope' => 'user_photos,publish_stream',
redirect_uri => 'https://apps.facebook.com/myappxxxxx');`

Answer (score 0):

When I change the url as below, it worked !!!!!

```
if(!$me) {  
    $url =   "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
                ."client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&"
                ."redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/APP_SLUG/&"
                ."scope=user_photos,publish_stream";
    echo "<script language=javascript>window.open('$url', '_parent', '')</script>";
} else {
    your code...
}
```

Thanks for the post