# Directly ask for permission in canvas app

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

Is there some new method for problem like this [Facebook - how to go directly to the request permission dialog with an iframe app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382017/facebook-how-to-go-directly-to-the-request-permission-dialog-with-an-iframe-ap) 
because answer from question in this link, isnt working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>
```

use this :)

Comment: thanks for quick respond ;) I am wondering, why this show me ugly dialog box ;/ not this cute dialog from others app ;/